# Return specific items from PDOException $e

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel-5

I have a try catch in my routes.php which works fine.

```
Route::get('{provider}/login', function ($provider) {
try
{
OAuth::login($provider, function ($user, $userDetails) 
{
    $user->email = $userDetails->email;
    $user->name = $userDetails->firstName . ' ' . $userDetails->lastName;
    $user->first_name = $userDetails->firstName;
    $user->last_name = $userDetails->lastName;
    $user->picture = $userDetails->imageUrl;
        $user->about = $userDetails->summary;
    $user->save();
    });

    return view('home');

} 
catch (ApplicationRejectedException $e) 
{
    // User rejected application
} 
catch (InvalidAuthorizationCodeException $e) 
{
    // Authorization was attempted with invalid
    // code,likely forgery attempt
}
catch(PDOException $err)
{
    return redirect()->guest('home');
}   
});
```

What I would like to do is to extract a specific item from the PDOException $err message.

If I attempt a login which I know will fail with a PDO exception, and I "dd" the error I get:

```
QueryException {#397 
#sql: "insert into `users` (`email`, `name`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `picture`, `about`, `facebook_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
#bindings: array:9 [?
0 => "mhluzi@email.com"
etc....
```

How do I just get the email address?

I have tried variations of

```
$err->binding[0]
```

etc with no luck.

Is that possible in any way?

Comment: Why can't you just use `$user->email`?

Comment: Because $user is not defined at that stage because the error occurred before it was created: "ErrorException in routes.php line 232: Undefined variable: user"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the following is returned:

```
catch(PDOException $err)
{
    $thisMessage=$err->getMessage();
    dd($thisMessage);
}
```

The whole string was available:

```
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'mhluzi@email.com' for key 'users_email_unique' (SQL: insert into `users`
```

etc.

So what I did was to replace the " ' " with " * "

and then was able to access what I needed.

```
catch(PDOException $err)
{
    $thisMessage = str_replace("'", "*", $err->getMessage());
    if(preg_match_all('/\*(.*?)\*/',$thisMessage,$thisMatch)) 
    {
        dd($thisMatch[1][0]); //first occurrence which is what we want
    }
}
```

output:

```
"mhluzi@email.com"
```